# Class 'FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\UserData' not found

Tags: facebook

We have recently decided to enable the Facebook Pixel on our Magento 2. Instructions were followed on the provided installation page.

The end result where "Setup" page should be found under Store>Facebook was successful. But after setting up the facebook ad manager, we noticed that the product links were broken.

Is there a documented fix to this?

Installation Steps:

1. Downloaded the Fb for Magento 2 zip file from Facebook
2. Uploaded the Facebook Extension under apps/code/FacebookExtension
3. PHP Setup. Compile. Upgrade.
4. Fb Extension app was enabled.
5. Run CRON 3x

I am not sure what I missed. Here's the error page when clicking a product. Links were changed.

[image: Product link redirects to this broken page on Magento 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed Facebook SDK?

If not,
Then install it by -
composer require facebook/php-business-sdk

as it is a dependency for the pixel to work properly

Also you will find a bash script in the zip file that you have downloaded.
You can run that script to install it.